# R: store dplyr pipe into a variable for lazy evaluation?

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to store a (partial) `dplyr` pipe into a variable and reuse it later?

For example `ggplot2` allows one to build the plot layers in parts enabling more modular code. I come from `data.table` "world" and I am new to `dplyr` "world".

A simplified example below. In my use case the filter pipes are longer and there is `if` - `else` logic that is repeated with several different filter sets. I am seeking ways to modularize the code. I would like to define components of the `dplyr` pipeline in parts and then compose the pipeline of the components.

```
ds_load_stats <- function(update = get_latest_update(),
                          cols = NULL,
                          premium = NULL,
                          ID = NULL,
                          server = NULL,
                          modN = NULL) {
  
  filename_stats <- file.path("data", "dataset_", update)
  DS.stats       <- open_dataset(filename_stats)

  if(is.null(cols)) {
    DT <- as.data.table(DS.stats %>%
                          filter((is.null(modN)      | account_id %% modN == 0) &
                                   (is.null(premium) | is_premium == premium) &
                                   (is.null(ID)      | id == ID) &
                                   (is.null(server)  | region == server)) %>%
                          collect())
  } else {
    DT <- as.data.table(DS.stats %>%
                          filter((is.null(modN)      | account_id %% modN == 0) &
                                   (is.null(premium) | is_premium == premium) &
                                   (is.null(ID)      | id == ID) &
                                   (is.null(server)  | region == server)) %>%
                          select(all_of(cols)) %>%
                          collect())
  }
  return(DT)
}
```

Comment: This is a very good question and Aurèle provided a very good answer! I will tag this as duplicate.

Comment: Thank you so much! `subchain <- . %>% verb(...)` is exactly what I was looking for.